# Delete elements in state array element in useEffect hook using props values

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I am trying to delete items from state variable in useEffect using the props comming to the component. I want to take initial values from state variable and then delete elements in that array and set the state variable again to new value. But When I don't pass the state variable in dependency array it is throwing warning as `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'abc'. Either include it or remove the dependency array` and when I pass it, It goes in infinite loop which I think is correct because of useeffect working. This is the useffect I am trying:

```
const [abc, setAbc] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then(res => setAbc(res));
}, [props.bbb])

useEffect(() => {
    if(props.xyz) {
         let aaa = abc.filter(key => key.id === props.xyz);
         setAbc(aaa);
    }
}, [props.xyz])
```

Is there something I am missing here? Is there any better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use `setAbc(currentAbc => currentAbc.filter(key => key.id === props.xyz))` and not provide `abc` as a dependency.

Comment: Curios, why do you have two `useEffect` hooks that have the same dependency ***and*** update the same state? Which do you want to win out and update state?

Comment: I assumed the two `useEffect`s should be one, I'm reading the intended logic as "On change of XYZ reload complete list and then filter based on XYZ" would need more information to be sure.

Comment: @JacobSmit I don't disagree, other than the first seems to be more the typical fetch data when mounting otherwise it doesn't make sense to run both each time the `xyz` prop updates. The promise chain of the first will overwrite any filtering the second did since it's asynchronous.

Comment: Hey. Actually I added the same variables here bymistake. Updated the code. Both use effect have different dependencies.

Comment: Thanks you @JacobSmit. setAbc(currentAbc => currentAbc.filter(key => key.id === props.xyz)) this worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, including a dependency that the effect updates will likely cause render looping. Use a functional state update to eliminate the need for `abc` as a dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (props.xyz) {
    setAbc(abc => abc.filter(key => key.id === props.xyz));
  }
}, [props.xyz]);
```

Since the first `useEffect` doesn't actually reference props I'm going to maybe assume you meant to only call this on mount. You can do this by using an empty dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(url).then(res => setAbc(res));
}, []);
```

#### Update

If you are wanting to fetch `abc` and filter each time the `props.xyz` dependency updates then use a single `useEffect` hook and filter the result before updating state.

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(url)
    .then(res => {
      if (props.xyz) {
        setAbc(res.filter(key => key.id === props.xyz));
      } else {
        setAbc(res);
      }
    });
}, [props.xyz]);
```

Comment: Thank you. Using abc like setAbc(abc => abc.filter(key => key.id === props.xyz)) worked.